# Angular2 + Babel + Gulp - Decorators won't convert to es5

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, babeljs

Babel is erroring when converting the decorators(@Component + @View) to es5. Am I missing something in my gulp file or how can I get this to work?

**ES2015 File (App.es6)**

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Alice';
  }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

**Gulp File**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('App.es6')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: What stage is your babel set to use? It should be set to `1` or lower if you want more functionality.

Comment: Not sure, so I guess the default. How can I tell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Babel 6

I had issues getting decorators working with Babel 6. As of today (2016-01-17), I get an error

> Decorators are not supported yet in 6.x pending proposal update.

The solution I had to do is use the [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy)

I had to install following npm packages:

- babel-plugin-syntax-decorators
- babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

My .babelrc looks something like

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have spent way too much time working on this. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

ES7 Decorators isn't enabled by default as they are only at the proposal stage of the ECMAScript spec. Babel has Stage 2 as default stage.

To enable Babel to use unstable features you can create a `.babelrc` in your project folder with the following contents

#### Babel5

```
{
    "stage": 1
}
```

You can also use `babel --stage 1` if you don't want to use a `rc` file.

#### Babel6

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-1"]
}
```

You can read more about the experimental features that Babel supports [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/)

Comment: In Babel 6, configuring stage 1 is done a little differently. Details here: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/